# calling a method ".class expected"

Tags: java, class, methods

when trying to run the start method from the main class using this code:

```
public class rungame {
    public void run() {
        Menu.start(string[]);
    }
}
```

and the method i am trying to run is:

```
    public class Menu{

    public static void start(String[] args){
        for( ; ; ){
            System.out.println("\nWelcome To The Block Game By Joe Easton\n");
            System.out.println("Enter S To Start");
            System.out.println("Enter H For Help");
            System.out.println("Enter E To Exit");
            System.out.println("\nWhat is your command?");

            //loop looking for input
            for( ; ; ){

                //private
                String answer;
                Keyboard kb = new Keyboard();
                answer = kb.readString();

                if(answer.charAt(0) == 'S' || answer.charAt(0) == 's' || answer.charAt(0) == 'H' || answer.charAt(0) == 'h' || answer.charAt(0) == 'e' || answer.charAt(0) == 'E') {

                    if(answer.charAt(0) == 'S' || answer.charAt(0) == 's'){
                        System.out.println("\nWhat is your name?");
                        String name;
                        name = kb.readString();

                        System.out.println("\nPress y to start");
                        String start;
                        start = kb.readString();

                        if(answer.charAt(0) == 'y' || answer.charAt(0) == 'Y') {

                        }

                        else{break;
                        }
                    }

                    if(answer.charAt(0) == 'H' || answer.charAt(0) == 'h'){

                                    System.out.println("\nIn this game, you have to avoid the B's by moving your character P. \nThe longer you last, the more points you get. \n\nTo move your character:\nUse the G key to go left\nUse the H key to go right\nUse the J key to go up\nUse the K key to go down");
                                    System.out.println("\nWhat is your command?");
                            }

                    if(answer.charAt(0) == 'E' || answer.charAt(0) == 'e'){
                    System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
                else{System.out.println("\nInvalid Command!");
                System.out.println("\nWhat is your command?");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a .class expected error when i try to run it from another class, the menu class compiles and runs fine

Comment: What do you think `string[]` means?

Comment: Just make `string[]` `null` if you're not going to use the `args` in your `start` method.

Answer (score 1):

what is `string[]`, you should pass valid instance of `String[]`

Comment: looks like the c# version of String[], or the type anyways

Comment: so would it be best to just delete the (string[] args)?

Comment: @JoeEaston if you're not using it, then yes. Or, if you plan to use it later then just pass in a null in your `run` method

Comment: if you do'nt need that argument just remove it

Comment: i have used it later in the code, i only pasted a shortened version, the menu class compiles and runs fine, i just need to run it within the rungame class

Comment: if it is allowed to pass null in your code then pass null, else just pass `new String[1]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running `rungame`, then I doubt how it is running, because it doesn't have a main method. It does have a run method, but the class neither implements the `Runnable` interface nor extends the `Thread` class.

Also the ambiguity of `string[]` as stated by others.

Also, if both the classes are in same file, then only 1 `public` class can be present in a single file. You would need to prepare separate files if you are attaching the `public` identifier to the class.

Check the above things, and then it should work fine.